# Rspec failing on custom exception

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

For some reason my Rspec test if failing when I'm expecting an exception to be raised.  I'm running Rspec v2.14.1, this is a custom Ruby app, `not` a Rails app.

Sample code:

```
# test.rb
class Test
  class BadError < Exception ; end
end
```

Spec File:

```
# test_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'test'

describe Test do
  it 'raises an exception' do
     expect( raise Test::BadError ).to raise_exception( Test::BadError )
  end
end
```

Result:

```
F

Failures:

  1) Test raises an exception
     Failure/Error: expect( raise Test::BadError ).to raise_exception( Test::BadError )
     Test::BadError:
       Test::BadError
     # ./spec/test_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.0005 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Not sure how to troubleshoot this either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put your code in a block so that RSpec can evaluate it, as in:

```
expect { raise Test::BadError }.to raise_exception( Test::BadError )
```

When you pass it as a parameter, the error gets raised before RSpec do anything.

Comment: Perfect, that worked.  Now to figure out why I had it as a parameter

Comment: When you're testing values and not behavior, you pass the object under test as a parameter.

Comment: oh I see: since the behavior has to be triggered and that requires the context of a block for the object to execute in.  Makes sense, thank you